# Assign a value to multiple cells in matlab

Tags: matlab, cell

I have a 1D logical vector, a cell array, and a string value I want to assign.

I tried "cell{logical} = string" but I get the following error:

```
The right hand side of this assignment has too few values to satisfy
the left hand side.
```

Do you have the solution?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You don't actually need to use `deal`.

```
a = cell(10,1); % cell array
b = rand(1,10)>0.5; % vector with logicals
myString = 'hello'; % string

a(b) = {myString};
```

Looking at the last line: on the left hand side we are selecting a subset of cells from `a` and saying that they should all equal the cell on the right hand side, which is a cell containing a string.

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks for posting this.  This is much more straightforward than using `deal`, but I somehow never picked up on needing to make the right-hand side into a cell array before doing the assignment.

Comment: You win the right answer for greater simplicity ;) (one year later)

Answer (score 14):

You can try this

```
a = cell(10,1); % cell array
b = rand(1,10)>0.5; % vector with logicals
myString = 'hello'; % string

[a{b}] = deal(myString);
```

It results in:

```
a = 

    'hello'
         []
         []
    'hello'
    'hello'
         []
    'hello'
    'hello'
         []
         []
```

Comment: Nice! It was impossible to find it on the internet... Can you explain why the []?

Answer (score 7):

As H.Muster said, `deal` is the way to go here. The reason for the brackets is that (following H.Muster's setup) `a{b}` returns a comma-separated list; the brackets need to be placed around this list to concatenate it into a vector. Running `help lists` in Matlab might further clarify, as might the documentation on [comma-separated lists](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/br2js35-1.html#br2js35-12)

**Edit:** The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14461462/1415355) provided by user2000747 seems much cleaner than using `deal`.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution can be

```
a = cell(10,1);
a([1,3]) = {[1,3,6,10]}
```

This may seem to be an unnecessary add, but say that you wants to assign a vector to 3 cells in an 1D cell array of length 1e8. If a logical is used, this would require creation of a logical array of size almost 100Mb.