# How to set a number in a couple of cells within a cell array

Tags: matlab, cell, cells

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Assign a value to multiple cells in matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11456381/assign-a-value-to-multiple-cells-in-matlab)

I am trying to enter a number, lets say 3, into all the cells in column 2 that are empty.

Like this:

```
emptyList = cellfun(@isempty,anscell)
anscell{emptyList(:,2),2}=3
```

but I get this message that

```
The right hand side of this assignment has too few values to satisfy the left hand side.
```

Can I overcome it without loops and creating sum and ones functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
anscell = cell(3,2)
emptyList = cellfun(@isempty,anscell)
anscell(emptyList(:,2),2)={3}
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you want to do?

```
[anscell{emptyList(:,2),2}] = deal(3)
```

Comment: well, it could be it, but it still does'nt work.  I think because the way I access my cells is bad, could be?